# How to fetch images from a string array and then get the base 64 from the file reader with async await?

Tags: javascript

I've obviously got some missing knowledge when it comes to async-await

I expect the base64 for each image to be logged one after another in the same order as the batch list array and then I expect `end` to be logged.

I'm getting a load of undefined and `end` logged first! Eeek!

```js
async function GetImages() {

  async function blobToBase64(blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      return reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }

  async function getBase64(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const base64 = await blobToBase64(blob);
    return base64
  }

  async function fetchBatchList() {
    const batchList = [
      "https://i.imgur.com/M0K21iS.jpg",
      "https://i.imgur.com/uNbsNAd.jpg", 
      "https://i.imgur.com/QdqhGb9.jpg"
    ];
    batchList.forEach(async url => {
      const res = await getBase64(url)
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
  
  async function end() {
   console.log('end')
  }

 await fetchBatchList();
 await end();

}

GetImages();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `async` to a function doesn't make it wait for the callback to be called.

You need to wrap your callback from `FileReader` in a `promise` to get the result.

You're also not awaiting anything in your `fetchBatchList` function. A good solution is to just map each item to a `promise` and then use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until all urls are finished.

```js
async function GetImages() {

  function blobToBase64(blob) {
    // Create promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      
      // Resolve value when done
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
      
      // Reject if we have an error
      reader.onerror = () => {
        reject(reader.error);
      }
      
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
  }

  async function getBase64(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const base64 = await blobToBase64(blob);
    return base64
  }

  async function fetchBatchList() {
    const batchList = [
      "https://i.imgur.com/M0K21iS.jpg",
      "https://i.imgur.com/uNbsNAd.jpg", 
      "https://i.imgur.com/QdqhGb9.jpg"
    ];
    
    // Map each url to a promise
    const list = batchList.map(url => {
      return getBase64(url)
    })
    
    // Wait until all are done
    const urls = await Promise.all(list);
    console.log(urls);
    return urls;
  }
  
  async function end() {
   console.log('end')
  }

 await fetchBatchList();
 await end();

}

GetImages();
```